# Почему в mozilla не работают яндекс-карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, firefox

Вот пример, во всех браузерах, открывается нормально, но не в firefox, максимум если вставить этот код на сайт, то будут заставки от яндекса, если прикрепить геометку, то она будет отображаться, в общем все кроме карты.

```css
div#map {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
filter: grayscale(100%), brightness(50%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.geoObjects&lang=ru-RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var myMap;

  function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [51.767481084662506, 55.113224784597655],
      zoom: 16
    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: для мозилы все портит `filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);`, если перенести его выше первого фильтра, то вроде все работает. По крайней мере `filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;...)` работает как надо